# How to get the wpnonce value?

Tags: plugins, nonce

On using inspect element to check the 'href' attribute of 'Deactivate' links for the plugins listed on plugins.php page, I found that the url contains a wpnonce field with a certain value. I need to get this value. For eg,

```
<a href="plugins.php?action=deactivate&amp;plugin=my-custom-css%2Fmy-custom-css.php&amp;plugin_status=all&amp;paged=1&amp;s&amp;_wpnonce=08a2b0d940" title="Deactivate this plugin">Deactivate</a>
```

How do I get this value '08a2b0d940' as in the above link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value is a random-ish string generated for one-time use with a lifespan of, if I remember correctly, 12 hours. I am not sure what you mean by "get" the value. Assuming you mean "generate the nonce" then...

You want [`wp_nonce_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url) or [one of the related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url#Related).

```
wp_nonce_url( $actionurl, $action, $name );
```

For example:

```
wp_nonce_url( 'http://www.google.com');
```

You can't regenerate the value if that is what you want but you could regex it out of the URL with PHP, circumstances permitting, or use Javascript to search the generated markup. Since I don't know *why* you are trying to do this, a solid answer is difficult.

Comment: I actually have no clue what to use to get the desired value. But will try ur suggestion !

Comment: That helped. Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but someone else might find this a useful function:

```
<?php
    function elab_disable_plugin_link( $plugin, $action = 'deactivate' ) {
        if ( strpos( $plugin, '/' ) ) {
            $plugin = str_replace( '\/', '%2F', $plugin );
        }
        $url = sprintf( admin_url( 'plugins.php?action=' . $action . '&plugin=%s&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s' ), $plugin );
        $_REQUEST['plugin'] = $plugin;
        $url = wp_nonce_url( $url, $action . '-plugin_' . $plugin );
        return $url;
    }
```

Then add your plugin name and filename to it.

ex.
`<a href="<?php echo elab_disable_plugin_link('my-custom-css-plugin/my-custom-css.php'); ?>">Disable Plugin</a>`